# How should a Jew behave if kidnapped by a non-Jew?

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, current-events

If a Jew is kidnapped by a non-Jew that he suspects may kill him, according to halacha how should he act? Meaning, should he try to escape or not?

Comment: The 2nd question, should he try to escape, seems "illogical". You are not allowed to do anything in anyway that allows you to be killed by someone, other than 3 situations, and none of them involve kidnapping with intent to kill. Perhaps, define the parameters of "suspects"? What would the kidnapper be doing? And, why should it matter if it's a Jew or non-Jew doing the action? Non-Jews are forbidden to kill, by the Noahide laws.

Comment: Halachically, the victim has one priority: [staying alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pikuach_nefesh). Consult your local police officer regarding the best way to do so in the described scenario.

Comment: @Fred - You mean CYLPO? BTW - an officer would probably advise that the best way to stay alive in this scenario is to use your gun, which, in many states you can't do, legally :-) Ya know, in these states, I think I would just stick to CYLOR first, and have him call the cops for you ;-)

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment: One Jew is not necessarily allowed to try to stay alive by doing something that could endanger other Jews (such as involvement in an effort to ransom himself for the release of murderers in prison).

Comment: @Fred Do you have a source for your second comment?

Comment: @DanF I don't think it's so simple; what if the kidnapper plans on selling you as a slave? Or using you for gilui arayos? That last one is discussed by poskim here and there

Comment: @Ypnypn It's a complex area of halacha. Hence my disclaimer: "not *necessarily* allowed".

Comment: @Matt - I agree with you on that, and I implied that by mentioning the "3 situations" where you must opt to be killed. That's why I think the question needs better focus. Considering that the comments (including mine) seem unfocused and there is no answer yet, it MAY indicate just this problem.